# Can jQuery UI Tabs load new complete HTML pages?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-tabs

I created an index.html page that have 3 different tabs. With the function `tabs()` of jQuery UI I want to load an html page with Ajax. Every HTML page use jQuery library, so every page have this code:

```
<link type="text/css" href="css/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" /> <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.min.js"></script>
```

If I click on a tab the page is loaded but the JavaScript function of the page doesn't work!

So can I load in a tab a new complete HTML page (HTML+JS)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,  the problem is to understand what the tabs do. With Ajax I can load some content in a tab.
If I declare a `<div>` for a tab, Ajax loads the content in that `<div>` so I can't load a new complete HTML page becouse the DOM after the load have two open `<html><head>` ecc.

So now I understand the function of the Ajax in the tab, and the load of complete HTML page is a big mistake!

Thanks Tobias.

Answer (score 2):

two possibilities:

1) if you need jquery-ui in each tab, it's better to load it when initalizing your tabs.

2) use following to load your javascript files: 
`$.getScript("js/jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.min.js");`
and for css: 
`$.get("css/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.css", function(css) {
$("head").append(""+css+"");
});`

Edit: You never load a complete new html page with ajax tabs - you only load a code snippet which is included in your existing html page. Use Firebug for Mozilla Firefox to see what happens ;o)

Comment: Why i never load a new html page? What is the problem?

Comment: in fact, you load a new html page - but it's not very clever to load a document which looks like that: <html><head> [...] because you include this document in your already existing document; so you have it twice. As a result of that, you can't access to the <head> tag to include scriptfiles. Instead you can use $.getScript().

Comment: So, if i understand if when i click on a tab, the content of a link page is added to the page? So if i have two tabs that link the same html page, the second tab not works becouse the DOM content is just place in the first tab! So how can i load a content and remove the previous dom?

Comment: you don't have to delete previous content, this happens automatically. If you want to prevent that the same javascript code is loaded twice, set a variable that it was loaded...